# How do I resolve Postgresql error, "could not determine which collation to use for string comparison"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-extensions

When ever I run this SQL script I get:

> ERROR:  could not determine which collation to use for string comparison

This is what is on line 34:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weight_options AS
  SELECT
    io.lot_id
    , io.vin
    , map.fkey_style AS chrome_styleid
    , SUM( CASE WHEN co.code = io.code THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS exact_option
    , SUM( CASE WHEN length(io.code) = 2 AND co.code LIKE io.code || '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS appx_option
    , (
      SUM( CASE WHEN co.code = io.code THEN 2 ELSE 0 END )
      + SUM( CASE WHEN length(io.code) = 2 AND co.code LIKE io.code || '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
    ) AS option_weight
  FROM inventory.options AS io
  -- options *must* have same index as inventory.vehicles
  JOIN chrome_vinmatch_best_match AS vd
    USING ( vin )
  JOIN chrome_vinmatch.style AS map
    ON ( vd.chrome_patternid = map.fkey_pattern )
  JOIN chrome_nvd.options AS co
    ON ( io.code = co.code AND map.fkey_style = co.fkey_style AND io.code IS NOT NULL )
  GROUP BY io.lot_id, io.vin, map.fkey_style
;
```

I just did a migration from an install of `8.4.11` to an install of `9.1.3` using `pg_dump`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the error in the [Release Notes for 9.1.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1-2.html)

> Make contrib/citext's upgrade script fix collations of citext columns
>   and indexes (Tom Lane)
>
> Existing citext columns and indexes aren't correctly marked as being
>   of a collatable data type during pg_upgrade from a pre-9.1 server.
>   That leads to operations on them failing with errors such as "could
>   not determine which collation to use for string comparison". This
>   change allows them to be fixed by the same script that upgrades the
>   citext module into a proper 9.1 extension during CREATE EXTENSION
>   citext FROM unpackaged.
>
> If you have a previously-upgraded database that is suffering from this
>   problem, and you already ran the CREATE EXTENSION command, you can
>   manually run (as superuser) the UPDATE commands found at the end of
>   SHAREDIR/extension/citext--unpackaged--1.0.sql. (Run pg_config
>   --sharedir if you're uncertain where SHAREDIR is.)

So I looked in that file for the `UPDATE` commands and found these:

```
UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_type SET typcollation = 100
WHERE oid = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype;

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_attribute SET attcollation = 100
WHERE atttypid = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype;

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[0] = 100
WHERE indclass[0] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[1] = 100
WHERE indclass[1] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[2] = 100
WHERE indclass[2] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[3] = 100
WHERE indclass[3] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[4] = 100
WHERE indclass[4] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[5] = 100
WHERE indclass[5] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[6] = 100
WHERE indclass[6] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);

UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_index SET indcollation[7] = 100
WHERE indclass[7] IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                      WHERE opcintype = 'citext'::pg_catalog.regtype);
```