#  How do I resolve Postgresql error, 'no collation was derived for column "foo" with collatable type citext'?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, collation, citext

Just recently I upgraded from Postgresql 8.4.11 to 9.1.3. I used pg_dump in the process. Now I'm getting an error:

> ERROR:  no collation was derived for column "vin" with collatable type citext
>   HINT:  Use the COLLATE clause to set the collation explicitly.

This is a continuation of the [problem that I had earlier](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17604/2639). It seems the fix suggested in the Release Notes did not catch [custom domains](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-createdomain.html). It seems as if the [CREATE DOMAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createdomain.html) statement in 8.4 didn't even support the `COLLATE` clause.

This is how I created the `vin` type,

```
CREATE DOMAIN inventory.valid_vin AS citext
  CHECK ( inventory.valid_vin( VALUE ) );
```

Comment: Ouch! My first instinct would be to alter any such columns to the base `citext` type, drop the domain, create it again, and alter the columns back; but that's a totally untested suggestion which might not be on target.

Comment: [I posted to the postgresql-general list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2012-05/msg00262.php).

Comment: Thanks for cross-linking your SO post and list post. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more information on this find our correspondence on this thread:

- Thread: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2012-05/msg00262.php

### Problem

The problem comes right from the horses mouth, Tom Lane,

> Well, if that's how you're creating citext *, then yeah it's broken.
>   As of 9.1 the citext type needs to be created with the attribute
>   "COLLATABLE = true".  The suggested UPDATE statements are a means
>   of correcting a failure to do that after-the-fact, but **they don't
>   cover any domains that have already been created on top of citext.**

Source: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2012-05/msg00262.php

`*` I was creating citext however my specific dump had it created, there was nothing special.

So a dump/restore from 8.3 -> 9.1 is not supported if you've got a domain over citext.

### Solution

You can get around this problem by first doing:

- `CREATE EXTENSION citext` before you load the dump.
- or, by hacking the patch to operate on `DOMAINS` over citext.